# AWS sns CloudWatch logs generating randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using AWS sns for push notifications on Android and Ios devices. To check if notifications are received or not, I am using cloud watch logs. 
Since, logs are not generated for every notification, so I am not able to check status for each notification.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  Please read [mcve] and [ask] to ask better received question. some time, some notification etc etc. You're question is unclear. add some code to show what you've done